# How do I use a recursion for sum of squares from user input?

Tags: java, algorithm, math, recursion

Let's say for the user input `1`, I can easily find the square of it. (A single digit input)
How do I use a recursive method to find the sum of squares (input with more than one number) e.g. `12345` should give `1*1 + 2*2 + 3*3 + 4*4 + 5*5 = 55`? For the base case, it is correct to as `num == 1` right? And from there, how do I compute the subsequent number behind `1`?

```
public static int squareSum(int num) {
    if (num == 1) {
        return num*num;
    } else {
        return 0; 
    }
}
```

Comment: The base case is the condition when the recursion stops, so thats the point when you output the result, dont start another calculation there.

Comment: @hamena314 Ohh I didn't know that... Thanks for the clarification.

Comment: If this is a homework task than it's ok, but I wouldn't recommend to use recursion for this type of computing (use a loop instead).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have to think about the small steps first. It is all about extracting the digits and the calculating the squares.

```
public static int squareSum(int num) {
    if (num == 0) return 0;
    return (num%10)*(num%10) + squareSum(num/10); 
}
```

For 12345 :-

```
f(12345) 

f(1234)+5*5

f(123)+4*4+5*5

f(12)+3*3+4*4+5*5

f(1)+2*2+3*3+4*4+5*5

f(0)+1*1+2*2+3*3+4*4+5*5
```

Comment: damnit, i only now realised he/she wanted a recursive solution. your code is nicer anyways

Comment: @coderredoc Can you explain why the base case should be num == 0 instead of num == 1?

Comment: You can add as many base cases as you want, actually. I would use 0 and 1 as base cases

Comment: Let's say if I use 1 as the base case, if the user input 0 there will be a StackOverflowError right?

Comment: @宿命的な孤独 well, if you use 1 as a base case what will happen if you call `squareSum(0)`? you'll get an infinite loop!

Comment: @LonelyNeuron Alright that explains what I was trying to ask! Thank you! But what if the user input a negative number?

Comment: @宿命的な孤独 yes! you could also define it as `If (num < 0) return 0;`, so it doesn't throw an exception when you pass negative numbers

Comment: @LonelyNeuron Isn't it better to put as (num <=0) return 0 in this case?

Comment: @宿命的な孤独 to understand why `squareSum(0)` would give you an infinite loop, you should try to work out the calls of the function one by one. you'll see that it never stops

Comment: @宿命的な孤独 yes, thats what i meant :o)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/158530/discussion-between-lonely-neuron-and-).

Comment: @宿命的な孤独.: Sorry for the late reply..the base case should be something that would be sure to be reached. Here if you divide all the integers by 10 ...it will eventually go to `0`..that's why the base case.

Comment: @coderredoc For recursion, the base case is something that we will get to in short is it?

Comment: @宿命的な孤独.: Yes you can say that...it will be the base case where our solution will reach eventually.

Comment: @coderredoc Alright thank you so much! I will read up more about recursion myself.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is, that you can't get the number at position x easily. The fact that `12345` consists of the numbers `1`, `2`, ... is only obvious in the decimal system. We will therefore store our number as a `String`, take each character and parse it to an integer. Then we square the number and add them

```
int i sum = 0;
String iAsString = i;
for (int i = 0; i < iAsString.length; i++) {
    int currentNumber = Character.getNumericValue(iAsString.charAt(i));
    sum += currentNumber * currentNumber;
}
```